# Starting Linux from USB while having Windows in hibernation

Tags: linux, windows, boot, usb

Is it possible to do this and if so, how?

I want to supend/hibernate my Windows 10 on my laptop and boot a linux (Ubuntu) from an external USB SDD.

My problem is: currently when i want to start the Ubuntu on my USB drive, i have to shutdown Windows to boot Ubuntu. But i don't want to shutdown Windows. I want to keep my open windows and work on with them after using Ubuntu.

Basicly i would want to use Ubuntu like a live system, but with its own USB drive which is writeable for it.

Comment: Possible but in general a bad idea, because you would have to make Linux to ignore all partitions that are mounted in Windows. Their state is "hibernated" as well so any modification to them can lead to serious problems like data loss.

Comment: Turn on Windows first and proceed normally. Vastly better and it makes no difference that Windows is running. You could also try turning Windows all the way off and then starting Linux

Comment: Turning off Windows Fast Startup and/or hibernation support would allow you to boot Ubuntu whenever you like. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

Comment: @Robert
 That would be appreciated. The Linux from USB should not use the internal disc. It should run totally independant.  If it would be easy to do, i would use two harddisks and switch them. But thats not that easy with may laptop ;-)

Comment: @Mokubai Sorry but i can not see how turning off Fast Startup and/or hibernation support can make this possible. What i think of is mor like: hibernate windows and then boot linux from usb. But when windows is hibernated, i don't know any way on how to boot from usb.

Comment: Don't use hibernate if you are intending to boot other operating systems. That's the basic advice. Hibernate and sleep put your OS (and potentially firmware) into a state that expects to boot up the hibernated system. You cannot trust even a LiveUSB to not change *something* that the hibernated system relies upon so the "cure" is to not let the system get into a state where that is a risk. To that end disabling hibernation means that your OS always shuts down cleanly ready for the other to boot.